# Высота динамического окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Создаю новое окно с заранее известной информацией

```
public partial class Chat: Window {
        public Chat(string name, string message) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.NameLabel.Content = name;
            this.MessageText.Text = message;
        }
}
```

Textbox с параметром `TextWrapping="Wrap"`

У окна задан размер, зависящей от содержимого `SizeToContent="Height"` `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"`

И всё отлично создаётся и подстраивается под размер, однако, когда я создаю объект этого окна, мне нужно сразу узнать его итоговую высоту

```
Chat notice = new Chat(name, message);
... + notice.Height ...
```

Но таким кодом я получаю ту высоту, которая была указана стандартной для этого окна. (Высота не успела измениться?)

При этом, если я попозже снова запрошу высоту окна, то она вернёт мне то значение, которое и должно быть, т.е. измененное в соответствии в содержимым.

Вопрос: как мне получить сразу изменённое значение высоты?

**UPD**

Сделал так:

```
Chat notice = new Chat(name, message);
notice.Loaded += (object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) => {
    ... + notice.Height ...
};
```

Правда, потом я всё в корне переделал, ибо, оказывается, создание и удаление 10-20 окон в секунду даёт излишнюю нагрузку.

Comment: `ActualHeight`?

Comment: хотя не совсем понятно зачем так делать если есть MVVM или Elmish

Comment: @FoggyFinder ActualHeight мне выдаёт 0, если я его сразу после создания запрашиваю, и нормальное значение, если потом. Вообщем, то же самое получилось

Comment: а если предварительно вызвать `UpdateLayout()`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Привязки вполне имеют право разрешиться на следующей итерации цикла сообщений, так что в общем случае этого недостаточно.

Comment: @VladD я понимаю, что такой способ не стопроцентный. Хотя в этом случае, пожалуй, может сработать. Но я пока не могу понять что именно хочет сделать автор, так как по постановке вопроса похоже на проблему XY

Comment: @FoggyFinder у меня весь интерфейс построен на WinForms, и на нём всё работало отлично, но необходимо было сделать для конкретного окна иной дизайн, который в WinForms не реализовать. Поэтому и переделал конкретно это окно в WPF

Comment: тогда понятно. Решения вам уже предложили хотя я бы еще рассмотрел возможность перевода проекта полностью на WPF, хотя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете в нескольких местах получить необходимые вам значения:

1. PageLoaded (Происходит, когда страница (или любой элемент) загружена, отрисована и готово к дальнейшему взаимодействию).
2. SizeChanged (Происходит когда ActualHeight или ActualWidth изменяются).
3. LayoutUpdate (Происходит когда изменяются элементы внутри базового объекта, на котором отслеживается это событие).

Ну и собственно простенький код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBlock.Text = "SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText";
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("MainWindow Size window w={0} h={1}", this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        this.LayoutUpdated += MainWindow_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void MainWindow_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("MainWindow_LayoutUpdated Size window w={0} h={1}", this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("MainWindow_SizeChanged Size window w={0} h={1}", this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("MainWindow_Loaded Size window w={0} h={1}", this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
    }
}
```

Не забывайте, что SizeChanged и LayoutUpdate могут часто вызываться. PageLoaded же будет вызван единожды.

Мне кажется это решение поможет вам решить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Окно в начале, после конструктора, на знает свой истинный размер. Например, если размер окна зависит от размера текста, то до реального рендеринга этого текста размер окна определить нельзя. Так что на время создания окна говорить об истинном размере бессмысленно.

Поэтому вам нужно делать не так. Либо получайте размер на событии `Loaded`, либо привязываетесь к нему через `Binding`, чтобы всегда иметь актуальное значение.